# How can I get the background image in full screen

Tags: html

[image]

I am just new to html ,and was deigning this page, I want the image to completely cover the background but rather it is showing something like this (pic given).
What should i change so that I can get a complete view (image covering the back ground completely.)

Here is my code.

Thanks in advance.

.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <title>Imperial</title>
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!--[if IE 7]><link href="css/font-awesome-ie7.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" /><![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/framework.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style1.css">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <!-- Contact Form CSS files -->
    <link type="text/css" href="./js-disclaimer/basic.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <!-- IE6 "fix" for the close png image -->
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
    <link type='text/css' href='js-disclaimer/basic_ie.css' rel='stylesheet' media='screen' />
    <![endif]-->
    <!-- Load jQuery, SimpleModal and Basic JS files -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js-disclaimer/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js-disclaimer/jquery.simplemodal.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js-disclaimer/basic.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="Body" style="zoom: 1;" class="cover">

    <a href="#" class="view-background"><i class="icon-eye-close icon-2x"></i></a>

    <div class="wrappers" style="background-image:url(./img/waw.jpg);">
  <!-- home -->
  <div class="main">
    <!---- menu area--->
    <div class="menu_area"> <img src="./img/logo.png" alt=""> <br>
      <ul>
        <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="worldaboveworld.html" title="world">World above the world</a></li>
        <li><a href="spaces.html">Spaces</a></li>
        <li><a href="safety.html" title="safety">Safety &amp; Security</a></li>
        <!----<li><a href="#" onClick="callPage('plan');" title="plan">Plans</a></li>--->
        <li><a href="plan.html">Plans</a></li>
        <!----<li><a href="location.html" title="location">Location</a></li>--->
        <li><a href="location.html">Location</a></li>
        <li><a href="enquiry.html" title="enquiry">Enquiry</a></li>
        <li><a href="address.html" title="contact">Contact Us</a></li>
        <br>
        <br>
        <li><a href="aboutsdk.html" title="SD">About SD Corp.</a></li>
        <li><a href="img/IE Bro20713 copy.pdf">ebrochure</a></li>
        <!--<li><a href="IE Bro20713 copy.pdf" target="_blank">E-Brochure</a></li>-->
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content">

        <div id="loader"></div>

        <ul class="grid blog one-col">
            <li class="enquiry" style="height:600px;">


                <div class="enquiry">
        <h1 style="text-align:center; margin-left:-40px; font-size:large;"><b>Fill in the spaces below</b></h1>
        <form onsubmit="return validation();" action="feedback_action.asp" method="post" name="form">
          <table cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0" style="margin:10px;" class="c">
            <tbody><tr>
              <td colspan="2"><table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="c">
                  <tbody><tr>
                    <td>You Are a :&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><input type="radio" value="buyer" name="youare">&nbsp; Buyer</td>
                    <td><input type="radio" value="agent" name="youare">&nbsp; Agent</td>
                    <td><input type="radio" value="other" name="youare">&nbsp; Other</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody></table></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><label>Name</label></td>
              <td><label>Mobile</label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="text" size="32" name="nameinput" id="userInput" value=""></td>
              <td><input type="text" size="30" name="mobileinput" id="Phone" value=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Address</td>
              <td>Landline</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td rowspan="3"><textarea name="addressinput" cols="26" rows="4"></textarea></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="landlineinput" size="30"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>E-mail</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="text" name="emailinput" style="" height="20"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Country</td>
              <td>City</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><select name="countryinput">
                  <option selected="selected" value="">Select Country</option>
                  <option value="United States">United States</option>
                  <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
                  <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
                  <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
                  <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
                  <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
                  <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
                  <option value="Angola">Angola</option>
                  <option value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option>
                  <option value="Antarctica">Antarctica</option>
                  <option value="Antigua and Barbuda">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
                  <option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
                  <option value="Armenia">Armenia</option>
                  <option value="Aruba">Aruba</option>
                  <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
                  <option value="Austria">Austria</option>
                  <option value="Azerbaijan">Azerbaijan</option>
                  <option value="Bahamas">Bahamas</option>
                  <option value="Bahrain">Bahrain</option>
                  <option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
                  <option value="Barbados">Barbados</option>
                  <option value="Belarus">Belarus</option>
                  <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
                  <option value="Belize">Belize</option>
                  <option value="Benin">Benin</option>
                  <option value="Bermuda">Bermuda</option>
                  <option value="Bhutan">Bhutan</option>
                  <option value="Bolivia">Bolivia</option>
                  <option value="Bosnia and Herzegovina">Bosnia Herzegovina</option>
                  <option value="Botswana">Botswana</option>
                  <option value="Bouvet Island">Bouvet Island</option>
                  <option value="Brazil">Brazil</option>
                  <option value="Brunei Darussalam">Brunei Darussalam</option>
                  <option value="Bulgaria">Bulgaria</option>
                  <option value="Burkina Faso">Burkina Faso</option>
                  <option value="Burundi">Burundi</option>
                  <option value="Cambodia">Cambodia</option>
                  <option value="Cameroon">Cameroon</option>
                  <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
                  <option value="Cape Verde">Cape Verde</option>
                  <option value="Cayman Islands">Cayman Islands</option>
                  <option value="Central African Republic">Central African Republic</option>
                  <option value="Chad">Chad</option>
                  <option value="Chile">Chile</option>
                  <option value="China">China</option>
                  <option value="Christmas Island">Christmas Island</option>
                  <option value="Colombia">Colombia</option>
                  <option value="Comoros">Comoros</option>
                  <option value="Congo">Congo</option>
                  <option value="Cook Islands">Cook Islands</option>
                  <option value="Costa Rica">Costa Rica</option>
                  <option value="Cote D'ivoire">Cote D'ivoire</option>
                  <option value="Croatia">Croatia</option>
                  <option value="Cuba">Cuba</option>
                  <option value="Cyprus">Cyprus</option>
                  <option value="Czech Republic">Czech Republic</option>
                  <option value="Denmark">Denmark</option>
                  <option value="Djibouti">Djibouti</option>
                  <option value="Dominica">Dominica</option>
                  <option value="Dominican Republic">Dominican Republic</option>
                  <option value="Ecuador">Ecuador</option>
                  <option value="Egypt">Egypt</option>
                  <option value="El Salvador">El Salvador</option>
                  <option value="Equatorial Guinea">Equatorial Guinea</option>
                  <option value="Eritrea">Eritrea</option>
                  <option value="Estonia">Estonia</option>
                  <option value="Ethiopia">Ethiopia</option>
                  <option value="Falkland Islands (Malvinas)">Falkland Islands (Malvinas)</option>
                  <option value="Faroe Islands">Faroe Islands</option>
                  <option value="Fiji">Fiji</option>
                  <option value="Finland">Finland</option>
                  <option value="France">France</option>
                  <option value="French Guiana">French Guiana</option>
                  <option value="French Polynesia">French Polynesia</option>
                  <option value="Gabon">Gabon</option>
                  <option value="Gambia">Gambia</option>
                  <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
                  <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
                  <option value="Ghana">Ghana</option>
                  <option value="Gibraltar">Gibraltar</option>
                  <option value="Greece">Greece</option>
                  <option value="Greenland">Greenland</option>
                  <option value="Grenada">Grenada</option>
                  <option value="Guadeloupe">Guadeloupe</option>
                  <option value="Guam">Guam</option>
                  <option value="Guatemala">Guatemala</option>
                  <option value="Guinea">Guinea</option>
                  <option value="Guinea-bissau">Guinea-bissau</option>
                  <option value="Guyana">Guyana</option>
                  <option value="Haiti">Haiti</option>
                  <option value="Heard Island and Mcdonald Islands">Heard Island and Mcdonald Islands</option>
                  <option value="Holy See (Vatican City State)">Holy See (Vatican City State)</option>
                  <option value="Honduras">Honduras</option>
                  <option value="Hong Kong">Hong Kong</option>
                  <option value="Hungary">Hungary</option>
                  <option value="Iceland">Iceland</option>
                  <option value="India">India</option>
                  <option value="Indonesia">Indonesia</option>
                  <option value="Iran, Islamic Republic of">Iran</option>
                  <option value="Iraq">Iraq</option>
                  <option value="Ireland">Ireland</option>
                  <option value="Israel">Israel</option>
                  <option value="Italy">Italy</option>
                  <option value="Jamaica">Jamaica</option>
                  <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
                  <option value="Jordan">Jordan</option>
                  <option value="Kazakhstan">Kazakhstan</option>
                  <option value="Kenya">Kenya</option>
                  <option value="Kiribati">Kiribati</option>
                  <option value="Korea, Democratic People's Republic of">Korea</option>
                  <option value="Korea, Republic of">Korea</option>
                  <option value="Kuwait">Kuwait</option>
                  <option value="Kyrgyzstan">Kyrgyzstan</option>
                  <option value="Latvia">Latvia</option>
                  <option value="Lebanon">Lebanon</option>
                  <option value="Lesotho">Lesotho</option>
                  <option value="Liberia">Liberia</option>
                  <option value="Liechtenstein">Liechtenstein</option>
                  <option value="Lithuania">Lithuania</option>
                  <option value="Luxembourg">Luxembourg</option>
                  <option value="Macao">Macao</option>
                  <option value="Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic of">Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav</option>
                  <option value="Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic of">Macedonia</option>
                  <option value="Madagascar">Madagascar</option>
                  <option value="Malawi">Malawi</option>
                  <option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
                  <option value="Maldives">Maldives</option>
                  <option value="Mali">Mali</option>
                  <option value="Malta">Malta</option>
                  <option value="Marshall Islands">Marshall Islands</option>
                  <option value="Martinique">Martinique</option>
                  <option value="Mauritania">Mauritania</option>
                  <option value="Mauritius">Mauritius</option>
                  <option value="Mayotte">Mayotte</option>
                  <option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
                  <option value="Micronesia, Federated States of">Micronesia</option>
                  <option value="Moldova, Republic of">Moldova, Republic of</option>
                  <option value="Monaco">Monaco</option>
                  <option value="Mongolia">Mongolia</option>
                  <option value="Montserrat">Montserrat</option>
                  <option value="Morocco">Morocco</option>
                  <option value="Mozambique">Mozambique</option>
                  <option value="Myanmar">Myanmar</option>
                  <option value="Namibia">Namibia</option>
                  <option value="Nauru">Nauru</option>
                  <option value="Nepal">Nepal</option>
                  <option value="Netherlands">Netherlands</option>
                  <option value="Netherlands Antilles">Netherlands Antilles</option>
                  <option value="New Caledonia">New Caledonia</option>
                  <option value="New Zealand">New Zealand</option>
                  <option value="Nicaragua">Nicaragua</option>
                  <option value="Niger">Niger</option>
                  <option value="Nigeria">Nigeria</option>
                  <option value="Niue">Niue</option>
                  <option value="Norfolk Island">Norfolk Island</option>
                  <option value="Norway">Norway</option>
                  <option value="Oman">Oman</option>
                  <option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
                  <option value="Palau">Palau</option>
                  <option value="Panama">Panama</option>
                  <option value="Papua New Guinea">Papua New Guinea</option>
                  <option value="Paraguay">Paraguay</option>
                  <option value="Peru">Peru</option>
                  <option value="Philippines">Philippines</option>
                  <option value="Pitcairn">Pitcairn</option>
                  <option value="Poland">Poland</option>
                  <option value="Portugal">Portugal</option>
                  <option value="Puerto Rico">Puerto Rico</option>
                  <option value="Qatar">Qatar</option>
                  <option value="Reunion">Reunion</option>
                  <option value="Romania">Romania</option>
                  <option value="Russian Federation">Russian Federation</option>
                  <option value="Rwanda">Rwanda</option>
                  <option value="Saint Helena">Saint Helena</option>
                  <option value="Saint Lucia">Saint Lucia</option>
                  <option value="Samoa">Samoa</option>
                  <option value="San Marino">San Marino</option>
                  <option value="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</option>
                  <option value="Senegal">Senegal</option>
                  <option value="Serbia and Montenegro">Serbia and Montenegro</option>
                  <option value="Seychelles">Seychelles</option>
                  <option value="Sierra Leone">Sierra Leone</option>
                  <option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
                  <option value="Slovakia">Slovakia</option>
                  <option value="Slovenia">Slovenia</option>
                  <option value="Solomon Islands">Solomon Islands</option>
                  <option value="Somalia">Somalia</option>
                  <option value="South Africa">South Africa</option>
                  <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
                  <option value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option>
                  <option value="Sudan">Sudan</option>
                  <option value="Suriname">Suriname</option>
                  <option value="Swaziland">Swaziland</option>
                  <option value="Sweden">Sweden</option>
                  <option value="Switzerland">Switzerland</option>
                  <option value="Taiwan, Province of China">Taiwan</option>
                  <option value="Tajikistan">Tajikistan</option>
                  <option value="Tanzania, United Republic of">Tanzania</option>
                  <option value="Thailand">Thailand</option>
                  <option value="Timor-leste">Timor-leste</option>
                  <option value="Togo">Togo</option>
                  <option value="Tokelau">Tokelau</option>
                  <option value="Tonga">Tonga</option>
                  <option value="Trinidad and Tobago">Trinidad and Tobago</option>
                  <option value="Tunisia">Tunisia</option>
                  <option value="Turkey">Turkey</option>
                  <option value="Turkmenistan">Turkmenistan</option>
                  <option value="Tuvalu">Tuvalu</option>
                  <option value="Uganda">Uganda</option>
                  <option value="Ukraine">Ukraine</option>
                  <option value="United Arab Emirates">United Arab Emirates</option>
                  <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
                  <option value="United States">United States</option>
                  <option value="Uruguay">Uruguay</option>
                  <option value="Uzbekistan">Uzbekistan</option>
                  <option value="Vanuatu">Vanuatu</option>
                  <option value="Venezuela">Venezuela</option>
                  <option value="Viet Nam">Viet Nam</option>
                  <option value="Virgin Islands, British">British</option>
                  <option value="Virgin Islands, U.S.">U.S.</option>
                  <option value="Wallis and Futuna">Wallis and Futuna</option>
                  <option value="Western Sahara">Western Sahara</option>
                  <option value="Yemen">Yemen</option>
                  <option value="Zambia">Zambia</option>
                  <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
                </select></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="cityinput" size="20"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody></table>
        </form>
      </div>




            </li>

        </ul>

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer" id="basic-modal" style="color:#000000;">&copy SDCPL 2013. All Rights Reserved&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" class="basic">Disclaimer</a></div>
<!-- modal content -->
<div id="basic-modal-content">
  <h3>Disclaimer</h3>
  <p>The content depicted herein is for general information and purely conceptual and is not legal offering nor will it be part of any binding document. The Developer reserves the right to delete, modify or supplement the content at any time for any reason without prior notification.</p>
</div>
</div>
<!--LOAD SCRIPTS-->
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/plugins.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For **CSS3**, add this style to your page using `background-size:cover;`:

```
<style>
  html { 
    background: url(YOUR IMAGE URL HERE) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    /* IE 9 and under*/
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='.myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
  }
</style>
```

If necessary, here is a **non-css3** solution:

CSS:

```
.bg {
  position: fixed; 
  top: -50%; 
  left: -50%; 
  width: 200%; 
  height: 200%;
}
.bg img {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  margin: auto; 
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 50%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

Body HTML:

```
<div class="bg">
  <img src="YOUR IMAGE URL HERE" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use it like this

```
body{
background:url("img_flwr.gif");
background-size:100% 100%;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: yes if you want your whole body to get that background if you want for any special div insted of body place that div id or past this css in that class of that div

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a library like jquery.backstretch.js which can be found here: http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/

Answer (score 0):

Just take for bg properties:

```
.bg{
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background-image: url('image.jpg');
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
```